# Need some help constructing a regex in Java

Tags: regex

I'm making a tool to find open reading frames for amino acids as a personal project. I have many strings that have characters consisting of the 26 uppercase English alphabet letters (A through Z). They look like this:

```
GMGMGRZMQGGRZR
```

I want to find all possible matches that are between the letters `M` and `Z`, with some additional rules.

1. There should not be any `Z`'s in between an `M` and a `Z`

   - Example: If `EMAZAZ` is the input string then `MAZ` should match, `MAZAZ` should not
2. There can be multiple `M`'s between an `M` and a `Z`

   - Example: If the input string is `GMGMGRZMQGGRZR` then `MGMGRZ` should match, but `MGRZ` shouldn't since there are more `M`'s before the first `M` in `MGRZ` that could be used to match.

## For Example

With the above string (`GMGMGRZMQGGRZR`), only `MGMGRZ` and `MQGGRZ` should match. `MGMGRZMQGGRZ`, `MGRZ`, and `MGRZAMQGGRZ` should NOT be match.

Does anyone know how to construct a regex like this? I consulted a few Java regex tutorials (I am using Java to write this program) but was unable to come up with a regex that followed all of the above rules.

The closest I have gotten is this regex:

```
M((?!(Z)))*Z
```

It shows that the substrings `MGMGRZ`, `MQGGRZ`, and `MGRZ` match. However, I do not want `MGRZ` to match.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is:

```
(M[^Z]+Z)
```

[**DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/vG2bZ4/2)

The regex works as follow: It will try to match an `M`, followed by any number of chars that are not a `Z` up to a `Z`

The thing is that every char is consumed only once from left to right, so in

```
GMGMGRZMQGGRZR
 ^----^         1st match MGMGRZ
       ^----^   2nd match MQGGRZ
```

And consequently, it will match `MGRZ` if you feed it alone to the regex !!

Comment: Just tried that, it still matches MGRZ, which I do not want.

Comment: @TheSalamander what condition is supposed to exclude it ? im lost in your text xD

Comment: Maybe I just explained it in a strange way, sorry. Let me try explaining it in more detail.

Comment: We have an input string. We start at the first index of the string and keep going to the next character until we see an M. Then we keep iterating until we reach the first possible Z. Therefore there can be multiple Ms between that first M we saw and the first Z we encounter, so MAMZ should be matched, but MZ shouldn't since MAMZ is already matched. After that Z, we keep iterating until we reach the next M, and then again, we keep iterating until the first possible Z. This repeats until we reach the end of the string.

Comment: @TheSalamander That's exactly how that regex works, but you still didnt say what condition should exclude the `MGRZ` !! is it because it doesnt have more than one `M` in it ?

Comment: We exclude the MGRZ since the MGMGRZ already encompasses the MGRZ. Since there is an M before the MGRZ, with no Z between those two M's, MGRZ is excluded.

Comment: @TheSalamander did you read the update ? You'll need to give more specifications/examples on the excluded cases to make up a rule out of it !! (I'll have to get to bed in 30 minutes though xD )

Comment: You are doing something funny if a substring of the match should somehow be excluded. The containing logic should probably continue from the end of the current match, not from the next character after the beginning of the current match, if you want to avoid rematching stuff which has already been matched.

Comment: This solution looks good for the given problem. Except when we have 'MZ'. Is this valid? If it is, the RegEx you are looking for is (M[^Z]*Z)